Ignore entire row if conversion is unsuccessful
To store enums as strings in the DB, I am using:
builder.Entity("Foo")
    .HasProperty("Bar")
    .HasConversion<string>()

However, if there is an entry in the DB that is not convertible, then an exception is thrown when fetching the record(s).
I want to just ignore those record(s) instead.
The only convention I could come up with is ensuring that all enums have a default value that is otherwise unused and then set up a query filter to exclude default. However, this would require a fairly extensive refactor of the codebase that I'd like to avoid.
Is there an alternative, such as custom converter that would cause EF to skip the record if it is otherwise unconvertable? To clarify, not skip the field (i.e. default or null), but skip the entire record.

Examples:
public class Foo
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public Bar Bar {get; set;}
}

public enum Bar
{
    A,
    B
}




Id
Name
Bar




1
Name1
A


2
Name2
B


3
Name3
C



var result = _dbContext.Foo.ToList();
Desired outcome is that result would only have 2 entries (records 1 & 2) not all 3 since C is not defined in Bar.

I'm prety sure that it's not possible to ignore / discard / skip "invalid" rows. The best alternative would be to configure Bar so that any string is allowed (which in fact is true), and then convert and/or filter using some custom .NET code after the entities have been loaded.

While it is possible (as the answers prove), I would strongly encourage you to fix either the database or your code so such hacks aren't necessary. Image what happens the day someone else takes over your code and try to understand.

I'd recommend writing your own enum to string value converter, so you can return default instead.

@JeremyLakeman I don't want default, I just don't want the record at all.

You can use a global query filter to setup a WHERE condition, which is added to all the queries related to your entity. Inside the HasQueryFilter() method specify the rows you want to have. In your case it can look like this:
builder.Entity<Foo>()
    .HasQueryFilter(p => p.Bar == Bar.A || p.Bar == Bar.B);

It will generate an SQL query like this:
[...] WHERE `u`.`Bar` IN ('A', 'B')


To build on top of other answer, just get the names of enum values (to not do it again with each query) and then define global filter:
var stringValues = Enum.GetNames<Bar>();

builder.Entity<Foo>()
    .HasQueryFilter(p => stringValues.Contains((string)(object)p.Bar));

Similair question

Will this work, given that p.Bar is an enum value?

@PeterB Thanks, right, it would not even compile. Corrected :)

Yes, you can do something like this, either with an explicit filter condition in the query (such as in a repository method) or a global query filter. If you want to only return rows that have a recognized enum value:
Global Query Filter:
Bar[] validBars = Enum.GetValues<Bar>();
modelBuilder.Entity<Foo>()
    .Property(x => x.Bars)
    .HasConversion<string>();
modelBuilder.Entity<Foo>()
    .HasQueryFilter(x => validBars.Contains(x.Bar));

As a regular query filter just move the validBars to where you want to query and add a Where condition:
var query = _context.Foos
    .Where(x => x.validBars.Contains(x.Bar);

The limitation of this approach is that you won't be able to read invalid rows using that entity, so I'd probably lean towards the global query filter then if you do need to read invalid rows, using a separate bounded DbContext with a different Entity definition parsing the column as a string.
